# Argue that $\mu_{Y|x}$ is a linear function of $x$

Tags: regression, linear-regression

> Note that if $|p|=1$, then $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X$. For fixed values of $X$, $Y|x = \beta_0 +\beta_1x$. Argue that $\mu_{Y|x}$ is a linear function of $x$.

Here is a question that I have recently encountered. This is my attempt in answering it.

$Y|x = \beta_0 +\beta_1x$
$\implies E(Y|x) = E(\beta_0 +\beta_1x)$ (taking the expectation of both sides)
$\implies \mu_{Y|x}=\beta_0 +\beta_1x$ (since $\beta_0 +\beta_1x$ can be treated as a constant)
and thus $\mu_{Y|x}$ is a linear function of $x$.

**Is my approach flawed, or is this acceptable?**

Comment: Sounds right to me. I expected you to be given $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a zero-mean noice, but you have an even simpler relation. In more general case I've describe the answer is still true.

Comment: Thank you. If you'd like, you can post this response as an answer below~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the definition of linearity w.r.t. $x$ is done via (partial) derivatives, i.e., check whether the derivative of $\mu_{Y|x}$ w.r.t. $x$ depends on $x$. Namely,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} E[Y|X=x] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}( \beta_0 + \beta_1 x) =  \beta_1,
\end{align}
which is not a function of $x$, hence your model is indeed linear.